# outliers with groupby in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data that are like that (toy data) :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N=5
dfi = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(5):
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range("20100101", periods=N, freq='M'))
    df['price'] = np.random.randint(0,N,size=(len(df)))
    df['quantity'] = np.random.randint(0,N,size=(len(df)))
    df['type'] = 'P'+str(i)
    dfi = pd.concat([df, dfi], axis=0)
dfi
```

From this I would like to calculate a new price per type ie something like that :

```
new_price = (1+perf)*new_price(t-1)
with : 
new_price(0)=price(0) 
and 
perf = price(t)/price(t-1) if abs(price(t)/price(t-1)-1)<s else 0
```

I tried :

```
dfi['prix_corr'] = (dfi
                   .sort_index()
                   .groupby('type').price
                   .apply(lambda x: x.pct_change() if x.pct_change().abs() <= 0.5 else 0)
                   )
```

but get an error message :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
``

I would like to correct in each group for outlier time series data. 
Any suggestion ?
```

Comment: What is `s` at `abs(price(t)/price(t-1)-1)<s`. Also, what do you want to achieve by correcting with outliers?

Comment: s is a number. For example 0.3. It is here to detect extreme variation of the price (I have split in my data but don't know when so it is a way to detect them) and from this construct a new price without these extremes mouvements because these are corrected with a 0 return

Answer (score 0):

Given your input, you could try using a custom function in your lambda expression such as:

```
def compute_price_change(x):
    mask = x.pct_change().abs() > 0.5
    x = x.pct_change()
    x[mask] = 0
    return x

dfi['prix_corr'] = (dfi
                   .groupby('type').price
                   .apply(lambda x: compute_price_change(x))
                   )
```

Output:

```
          price quantity type prix_corr
2010-01-31  3      0      P4    NaN
2010-02-28  3      2      P4    0.0
2010-03-31  0      2      P4    -0.5
2010-04-30  2      4      P4    0.5
2010-05-31  2      2      P4    0.0
2010-01-31  1      2      P3    NaN
2010-02-28  4      3      P3    0.0
2010-03-31  0      0      P3    0.0
2010-04-30  4      0      P3    0.0
2010-05-31  2      2      P3    0.0
     .      .      .      .      .
     .      .      .      .      .
     .      .      .      .      .
```

Since `.pct_change()` returns `NaN` for the first entry, you might want to handle that in some way as well.